# Can I add file names next to the line count value to its specific file with this for loop?

Tags: bash

I have 3 files, `test1`, `test2`, `test3`.

I'm trying to put the line count of each file and the file name, in a list, and then that list in the body of an email.

This is a rough sketch of what I have so far. I'm not sure how to get the file name into the `email-body` file. I know how to send the email with the `email-body` text.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/home/tst/test-dir/${@:1}

for files in $FILE
 do
  cat $files |wc >> temp-word-count;
  cut -d " " -f 7 temp-word-count > email-body;
 done
```

Comment: `for files in $FILE; do wc $files >> temp-word-count; done` Calling `wc $files` will include the filename after the counts, unlike when piping to `wc` (e.g. when `wc` is reading from `stdin`) If you really want the name before the counts, then `printf "%s %s\n" "$files" "$(wc < "$files")"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply passing discrete filenames as arguments to your script that are located in your `/home/tst/test-dir` directory and you want the *line-count* and filename in `email-body`, then you can use a simple loop as well, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/home/tst/test-dir

:> email-body       ## truncate email-body before each use
for files in "$@"   ## loop over arguments
do
    wc -l "$dir/$files" >> email-body   ## add line-count and name to email
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using my directory `$HOME/tmpd` and calling the script as:

```
$ bash tmp/embody.sh afile cmtfile file sfile
```

results in the file `email-body` in the present directory containing:

```
$ cat email-body
8 /home/david/tmpd/afile
8 /home/david/tmpd/cmtfile
6 /home/david/tmpd/file
12 /home/david/tmpd/sfile
```

Your other option, that will be slightly more efficient, is to simply redirect the output of the `for` loop a single time at the time of completion, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/home/tst/test-dir

for files in "$@"           ## loop over arguments
do
    wc -l "$dir/$files"     ## output line-count and name
done > email-body           ## single redirect to email at end of loop
```

This eliminates the need to truncate before the loop as well. (same output in `email-body`)

Comment: You could redirect with `> email-body` outside of the for loop instead of first truncating and then appending for every iteration.

Comment: Yes correct you are. Enclosing the loop in `{ ... }` and redirecting at the end would be optimal.

Comment: You don't need `{}` either, just `for ...; do ...; done > email-body` would work, no?

Comment: Good point, the loop provides the enclosing scope -- updated to add the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`wc` already does the work for you and lists filenames with line counts:

```
$ wc -l test?
 3 test1
 6 test2
 2 test3
11 total
```

So, if your files live in `/home/tst/test-dir`, you can use something like

```
wc -l /home/tst/test-dir/test? > email-body
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
{ numLines[FILENAME]++ }
END {
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        fname = ARGV[i]
        print fname, numLines[fname]+0
    }
}
' "/home/tst/test-dir/${@:1}" > email-body
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(haven't tested it).

```
awk '
FNR==1 && prev{
  print prev_file, prev
}
FNR==1{
  prev_file=FILENAME
}
{
  prev=FNR
}
END{
  print prev_file, prev
}  
' "/home/tst/test-dir/${@:1}" > email-body
```